# Is there a way to find who starred messages in a chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat-stars

Is there a way to find who starred messages in a chat room?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, no. What's up?   You don't like spam?

Comment: No i don't. I want to find who starred messages because in the morning some one play game with us some one starred all the messages on the chat room. As i am admin of that chat room. I want to remove that guy.

Comment: I know how you feel.  I virtually gave up with the Lounge because some idiot member persisted in running an annoying script that continually added and removed stars.

Comment: Ya exactly. so much annoying

Comment: No there isn't. There used to be, through a websocket vulnerability, but no more.

Comment: No, sadly the devs took away the ability to see who starred a message several weeks ago now.

Comment: @MD I think that's possible with a feature-request and a meta post, if it gets lot of support.

Comment: @PhMgBr Yes that's right but i don't think people are really interested in this

Comment: Yeah - it's frustrating when that happens. If it continues after un-starring and posting a message in the room asking people to not bulk star - the best you can do for now is flag one of the starred messages and state that you have a star spammer (or maybe even someone who doesn't understand how starring works and just really likes your messages?). Note that you'll have to be patient for a response as the only way I know of now (and has been used before) is to request a db dump for stars of a room from a dev so mods can have a look to see if it's malicious or just ill-guided.